# JSON object from messenger chatbot in PHP

Tags: php, json, messenger, chatbot

I'm using messenger chatbot with script below from [Mr Nadeem Manzoor's tutorial](https://medium.com/@nadeem.manzoor0/facebook-messenger-platform-web-hook-setup-in-php-893ead06746b#.hdtuobu0q)

When I receive json object on line 15th:
 `$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`
I want to save whole object as a text in .txt file. How is it possible to do? I'll appreciate any help. 
There is whole script:

```
    <?php

/* validate verify token needed for setting up web hook */
if (isset($_GET['hub_verify_token'])) {
    if ($_GET['hub_verify_token'] === 'codeandpepper') {
        echo $_GET['hub_challenge'];
        return;
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid Verify Token';
        return;
    }
}

/* receive and send messages */
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
if (isset($input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id'])) {

    $sender = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['sender']['id']; //sender facebook id
    $message = $input['entry'][0]['messaging'][0]['message']['text']; //text that user sent

    $url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages?access_token=EAAQyP47lxSQBAPQSXyHhQ7y0d0MTQgTn4xaFEDEu5yrc4qo4t0FWbHZAfT7TFQq3HYZCUGVcTPZAaN2ZBNrUShl4Hr5qQd8cqBu0mfB0Al7NZAWjIjQC9UqXQLU5E9IsZBaQDIXglMcEBqNUyiidGJWRPPfvCmtg4vy2UgUhU8SQZDZD';

    /*initialize curl*/
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    /*prepare response*/
    $jsonData = '{
    "recipient":{
        "id":"' . $sender . '"
        },
        "message":{
            "text":"You said, ' . $message . '"
        }
    }';
    /* curl setting to send a json post data */
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonData);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    if (!empty($message)) {
        $result = curl_exec($ch); // user will get the message
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Clarify please: You want to save the JSON String to a file, or the resulting array from `json_decode()`? Both are pretty simple

Comment: I want json string, not array made from it, but if is it simple I'd like to see both examples :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the JSON String, and that would be the simplest and cleanest thing to do then you will have to break this line up and then just `file_put_contents()` the string to a file name

```
/* receive and send messages */
$input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Into

```
/* receive and send messages */
$json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
file_put_contents('path/to/file.txt', $json_str);
$input = json_decode($json_str, true);

// and off you go as normal
```

Comment: thanks, but it's not working, I think thats because I want to save it to a file which is on server, I've got  `Warning: file_put_contents('path': failed to open stream: Permission denied in 'path' on line 17`

Comment: The filename I used `'path/to/file.txt'` was just an example. You have to replace that with a valid path and filename or your server and check that you servers user account has the correct rights to write to that directory

Comment: path is correct, the thing was that I have to change file permissions in filezilla - it's working now, thanks